# How to use INDIRECT (or alternative) in an Array into a Matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-merge

I want to merge multiple arrays that are in multiple sheets into a single matrix with the size of **Max(Columns(arrays)) x Count(arrays)**.
See image bellow to better understand the inputs and expected results.

Input values and expected results image

[image]

https://www.mediafire.com/file/g832c50izpqrnu5/IndirectErrorExample.xlsx/file

The expected result is the last one, recreated with `HSTACK`. However, this method is executed by brute forcing all different inputs and is not dynamic.

The second example is just to show that the `INDIRECT` formula works individually.

Lastly, the first example is how I tried to execute, calling a transposed array as input and expecting a matrix output.

Is there something I can do to fix this `#VALUE!` error in this case? Or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

### REDUCE/HSTACK With INDIRECT

[image]

```
=IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",A1:A3&"#",LAMBDA(rr,r,
    HSTACK(rr,INDIRECT(r)))),,1),"")
```

**Edit**

- **Mayukh Bhattacharya** suggested this, IMO, improvement:

  ```
  =DROP(IFNA(REDUCE("",INDIRECT(A1:A3&"#"),
      LAMBDA(rr,r,HSTACK(rr,r))),""),,1)
  ```

  Note how `IFNA` needs to go after `DROP` to be applied to a smaller array (range).

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I thought no way so I didn't even consider it. Also, `IFNA` needs to go after the `DROP` as you are suggesting. Nice catch. Not my day today.

Comment: Or, drop the `DROP`, and make it properly dynamic: `=IFNA(REDUCE(,INDIRECT(INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)))&"#"), LAMBDA(rr,r,HSTACK(rr,r))),"")`

Comment: @SpectralInstance Nice, but you can golf it by using `TOCOL()` : `=IFNA(REDUCE(,INDIRECT(TOCOL(A:A,1)&"#"),LAMBDA(rr,r,HSTACK(rr,r))),"")`

Comment: @SpectralInstance I see, dropping the `DROP` works (never mind the dynamics) but I can't see why. Considering [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76678903) about omitting the `initial_value` parameter, what is the difference that I'm not realizing?

Comment: I ended up using the solution with `TOCOL()`. It worked like a charm.
Also, in my original file, I had another problem that not all data arrays had their address listed. In fact, it should consider another information that was already created using Defined Names. I was able to filter the ones I had the address using another `TOCOL()` nesting the whole formula with parameter 3.
And to include the other information, I included an index row in my matrix and filtered in each matrix the ones I wanted to use. Then I used `HSTACK()`, `SORT()` and `DROP()` to finish.